# Why do we use limit and long division to figure out the Oblique and Horizontal Asymptote?(rational function)

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Well, we use long division to find the quotient and use the concept of limit to make x -->+-∞ to ignore the remainder and the rest(quotient) is the asymptote we are trying to find. But why this quotient is the asymptote? why do we use "long divison" to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that polynomial long division will break your rational function into a polynomial (which might go to zero, or to a nonzero constant, or blow up, it depends) plus a rational function which will go to zero at $\pm \infty$ (because the degree of the denominator will be higher than that of the numerator). The first piece is the quotient; the second piece is the remainder divided by the divisor. The second piece will not contribute to the asymptotic behavior at $\pm \infty$, so to study that behavior we isolate the first piece from the second by doing the long division.